# jQuery not selecting element

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing a program that creates boxes when I click a button. I have a "model" box hidden so when I click the button, it clones the model box and changes its id.

Inside this boxes I have a link that have to do some function when clicked, but jQuery seems unable to find this element, so I get nothing when I click the link.

Here's my code:

```
$('#box-' + number).find('a').click(function(){
     alert('boop'); //function
});
```

Variable 'number' is the number of the box. As I said the ID is changed when I clone the model box.

The model box is something like this:

```
<div id="box-model">
   <div class="box">
      <div class="heading">
         <a class="link-class">¡Click Me!</a>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
         CONTENT
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may just be due to the level of abstraction, but you'd be better using `on` to delegate, something like... `$(document).on("click",".box a",function(){...});`.  I can't see anything wrong with your example, so maybe the creation of the box from the model is not working. Do you have a fiddle or codepen example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events to dynamically added element.

As the ids are generated dynamically, you can not use them as selector in event delegation. you can rether use class selector to target anchor elements inside `.header`:

```
$('body').on('click','.heading a',function(){
  alert('boop'); //function
});
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! But now, how can I recognize the box that the user use to click the link?

Comment: You will get context of clicked element (`this`) in clicked event.  You can convert it to jquery object and do the needful.'

Answer (score -1):

```
$("body").find('#box-' + number).find('a').click(function(){
     alert('boop'); //function
});
```

The thing is, jQuery has loaded DOM before the box is generated. Assuming this code is in your $(document).ready(function()), your boxes are not yet generated when the document is ready. You need to go to "#box"'s parent element that was generated at the start (it doesnt have to be body)

Comment: This does not work. You're not delegating the event, you're still attaching it to only elements that exist at the time the event is created, regardless of whether or not you're using an existing element like `body` to find them. [Here's an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/9f6qbnvb/2/) (I've included the solution in this link, which is *Event Delegation*, as Milind Anantwar posted above.)